# Why doesn't interceptor's onLoad() work?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, interceptor

We have a jboss based system

persistance.xml looks like a following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="solutions" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/mam</jta-data-source>

        <class>....</class>
        ......
        <class>....</class>

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>

            <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource" value="java:/mam"/>
            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:/solutions"/>

            <property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor"
                      value="interceptor.AuditAndDeletableCatcherInterceptor"/>

            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false"/>

            <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer" value="cglib"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="com.magenta.componentization.audit.sql.MySQL5CustomDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.query.substitutions" value="true 1, false 0"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class"
                      value="org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider"/>
            <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread"/>

            <property name="cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Interceptor's code:

```
public class AuditAndDeletableCatcherInterceptor extends AuditInterceptor {

    DeletableCatcherDeligate deletableCatcherDeligate =
            new DeletableCatcherDeligate();

    @Override
    public boolean onLoad(Object o, Serializable serializable, Object[] objects, String[] strings, Type[] types) {
        deletableCatcherDeligate.onLoad(o, serializable, objects, strings, types);
        return super.onLoad(o, serializable, objects, strings, types);
    }
}
```

Where AuditInterceptor extends native hibernate's EmptyInterceptor 
and overload some methods like onSave(), onFlush(), onPreFlush()

Some methods of the AuditAndDeletableCatcherInterceptor work, but onLoad() is never called.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

onLoad is only called if the object is being retrieved from the database and not the cache. if the object is already managed, then the onLoad is not called.  You can test this by implementing PrepareStatement and seeing what its doing.  What I do is implement all the methods and log them all when writing an interceptor, then I know exactly what its doing.